# Is there a site for literature?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there any Stack Exchange site where the main topic is literature?

I have tried the English Language site, but it seems that it is not the appropriate site.

Perhaps the writers site would work? But, then again, the main point is different than the one I am searching for.

Comment: Please clarify what main point you are after.

Comment: Literature in general, criticism of novels, poems, etc.

Comment: This is not objectively answerable (hence, not fit for Stack Exchange). You can try reddit and its clones (voat.co etc.), though.

Comment: Sir, I cannot find reddit, what is it?

Comment: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com).

Comment: They should create Literature Stack Exchange.

Comment: @user135395 - Well volunteered! You can submit your proposal on [SE Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). Good luck! :-)

Comment: @user135395 We used to have a Literature site. It unfortunately didn't work out well and was closed.

Comment: Questions about literary criticism are off-topic on Writers.

Comment: @user135395 [They did](http://literature.stackexchange.com/) :-)

Answer (score 18):

### Yes!

[Literature](http://literature.stackexchange.com) is currently in public beta - anyone can participate, and the site is thriving. Come along and join us in asking and answering all manner of questions about literature!

Answer (score 12):

There is a [literature proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238/literature) on [Area 51](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange#History). It's now in Public Beta so anyone can participate.

Answer (score 5):

Currently on Area 51, there is [a proposal literally called *Literature*](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238/literature).

So the site is not made yet, but it is currently trying to reach the commitment stage and finally the beta stage, where the site will be launched to see whether the site can graduate and be an official site. If you want to help make the site successful, follow the proposal here after making an account on Area 51.

You can try making a new proposal for Literature on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) if you want. Good luck on the Literature proposal, if you make the proposal or follow the current proposal...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the suggestion for supporting the Literature proposal on Area51, I would also like to point out to you that questions about literature in the fantasy and science fiction genre are well on-topic in the [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site.

Comment: This is true but *criticism*, which the OP requests, is off-topic on SF&F.SE.